# Python: replace single character in value of dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary, replace

How do I replace a single character in a string for Python dictionaries for a matched if condition?

Given:

```
if key[-1] == "d" and val[-1] == "t":
  print key, val

versed v3rst
vexed vEkst
voiced vOIst
```

I want to change the final letter "t"s to "d"s.  I tried:

```
if key[-1] == "d" and val[-1] == "t":
  val[-1] = val[-1].replace("t", "d")
  print key, val
```

However I get the error:

```
val[-1] = val[-1].replace("t", "d")
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Any tips? It seems like a simple if and replace.

Comment: Strings are immutable. You can't modify a string in place; you have to replace the whole thing with a new object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings are immutable, you can't change a character by assignment. You can use `replace`, if you do e.g.

```
val = val.replace(...)
```

But to change only the last character you need:

```
val = val[:-1] + val[-1].replace(...)
```

Or just:

```
val = val[:-1] + "d"
```

However, this still won't update the dictionary, again because strings are immutable and this creates a new object. To do that:

```
d[key] = ...
```

Comment: ```repalce()``` will change all ```t```s to ```d```s, which I don't believe is what OP wants.  ```val = val[:-1] + "d"``` should work though

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, string can't be modified, since they are **immutable** (See http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-are-python-strings-immutable.htm for example).

You need to do what you want, you can do the following:

```
if key[-1] == "d" and val[-1] == "t":
  val = "%sd" % val[:-1]   # Take the val, except the last character and add a "d"
  print key, val
```

You can't use `replace` here, otherwise it will change every `t` in your string by `d` (even those at the beginning of the string)